# How to store files in Couchbase database using Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I have a JSON document having some properties including attachment(abc.txt).

How to save attachments in couchbase using Node.JS?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Couchbase [Node.JS SDK](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/node-2.0/introduction.html)

You have two choices in how to store the attachment:

**Inline with the document.** If the attachment is small and/or easily embedded into JSON (the attachment is valid JSON itself) then you can simply add a element to your JSON document containing the attachment body, for example:

```
{attachment_name: "abc.txt",
 attachment_body: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n"
 ...
}
```

**As a separate document, referenced from the first.** If the document is large / you don't want to serialize it inline, then create a field which just refers to the key of the actual attachment:

```
{attachment_name: "abc.txt",
 attachment_ref: "attachment::document1_attachment1"
 ...
}
```

Then you'd have a second document named `attachment::document1_attachment` which was the actual attachment document.